# How do I actually setup SSO with Vanilla jsconnect?

Tags: php, jsonp, vanilla-forums

I have a site with a basic members auth system built into it, I wanted to allow the logins for this site to also work on a vanilla forum using the jsconnect plugin. The forum is built within a folder of the site.

I've been through the documentation for the jsconnect plugin for vanilla forum.
However I can't quite grasp the process of actually setting it up, This is where I'm at right now;

I've downloaded and installed the jsconnect plugin within vanilla forum, I can access it within settings. However when i try to add a connection, once I hit submit I get a blank error screen:

```
Something has gone wrong.

We've run into a problem and are unable to handle this request right now.
Please check back in a little while.
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with me needing to have set up an Authenticate Url that goes somewhere, however what is it supposed to point to?

I read that I need to have a jsonp file however when i look at the jsconnect repo https://github.com/vanilla/jsConnectPHP Theres an index.php file that seems to handle the authentication, is that right?

Essentially I'm looking for some guidence on how I should proceed,

Any help would be sure appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you need to download the index.php file, then change the path for functions.jsconnect.php to `/plugins/jsconnect/functions.jsconnect.php`.

then add a connection and test url.